# when to use a format file for bulk copy program (bcp)

Tags: sql-server, format, bcp

When would we use a format file for bcp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you have different column separators.

For example: `bob,"fred","tom"||harry` rather than `bob,fred,tom,harry`

The section ["When Is a Format File Required?"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337558(SQL.90).aspx) describes it completely